# Choosing proper min_gram and max_gram ngram values

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, n-gram

What are the benefits of using ngram analyzer with min_gram:3 max_gram:10 over ngram analyzer of min_gram:3 and max_gram:3?

When min_gram equals to max_gram the db size will be much smaller compared to the scenario in which min_gram and max_gram differs.

When min_gram and max_gram are smaller than the query itself, the query will be brocken no chunks of max_gram sizes and I will still be able to find "Opel" when max_gram equal to 3.

Am I missing something?

Could it be related to ranking?

Sarching with "Opel" when max_gram equals 4 will give better rank than searching "Opel" when ngram equals 3?

What are the bennefits of using ngram (not edge ngram) when min_gram and max_gram have different values?

Answer (score 1):

This might be true but might be not. Depends how many words you have with "ope" in them. You might loose opel instead of open, opera, oped, operand, etc. Especially if this is not an edge ngram, than you will have also words like hope, rope, etc. But on relatively small scale (for example searching in car brands that might produce acceptable results)